# git init doesn't create .git directory

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git, when I run `git init` in the terminal there's no .git directory created, however i get this result `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/Desktop/Javascript/sotrustme/.git/`

please help me

Comment: It's there. but it's hidden. Git is not something it's meant to access using folders and stuff, and it's not exactly possible - in the way you think of it. Learn what git is and how it works in the first place. If you really want to see the hidden `.git` folder, in the folder where you initialized git use `ls -a` from your CLI

Comment: try an `ls -a` for "all"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others already mentioned, the `.git` directory is *hidden* from normal view, by virtue of being named `.git`.  Files and directories with names starting with `.` are normally not displayed, to keep things uncluttered.

There's one other important point:

> ... I get this result `Reinitialized existing Git repository in ...`

(the boldface is of course mine here).  This means you *already have* a Git repository.  Your `git init` is not wiping it out, it's just checking that it looks like a valid Git repository, and making sure any template-specific hooks are set up.  (This last part does not affect you: it would only matter if you ran `git init --template=<some alternate template directory>`.)

Answer (score 4):

It should be a hidden folder.

Try to display the hidden folders and you should be able to see it.

Use `ls -al` to view all the hidden files and folders and their properties.

Answer (score 1):

`git init` Will create a .git folder (which is .) means a hidden folder.

> The error `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/Desktop/Javascript/sotrustme/.git/`

This means .git already exist in your Present Working Directory. You can view the .git folder (and all hidden files and folders) by this command

```
ls -a
```

You can run `git status` to check status, if it works git is initialized and working.

Answer (score 1):

You can also verify that the directory is there on your command line by running this command: `ls .git`.

You should then see the hidden folders listed in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on Hidden Files in view section in file explorer:[image: 1]]

Comment: "Hidden Files"? This is Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`.git` is a hidden directory. You wouldn't expect it to be in public view. In Linux, you will have to use `ls -a` to view the hidden directory.

You also have:

> Reinitialized existing Git repository

What does that mean? That means that the repository is already created so when you run that it becomes initialized again so the old files from Git should be deleted by the time you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue where I was getting the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQg45.png)

But then I noticed I had some security notifications on my windows system.

[Windows Security notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPeeg.png)

After allowing this action from here I was able to use the "git init" along with other commands as well.